# Rails delegate and alias - infinite loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activesupport, activesupport-concern

I don't understand the following infinite loop involving `delegate` and `alias`

```
class Company
  field :name
end

class Employee < Professional
  include CompanyMember
end

class Professional 
  include UserProfile
end

module CompanyMember
  belongs_to :company
  delegate :name, to: :company, prefix: true
  alias :organization_name :company_name
end

module UserProfile
  def to_s
    out = "#{name} "
    out += "(#{organization_name})" if respond_to?(:organization_name)
  end 
  def inspect
    to_s + super
  end
end
```

I have an `Employee` with a missing company, and I have the following infinite loop

```
app/models/concerns/user_profile.rb:94:in `inspect'
app/models/concerns/company_member.rb:8:in `rescue in company_name'
app/models/concerns/company_member.rb:8:in `company_name'
app/models/concerns/user_profile.rb:89:in `to_s'
app/models/concerns/user_profile.rb:94:in `inspect'
app/models/concerns/company_member.rb:8:in `rescue in company_name'
app/models/concerns/company_member.rb:8:in `company_name'
app/models/concerns/user_profile.rb:89:in `to_s'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your override of `inspect`. When you attempt to call a delegated name on a missing company, `NoMethodError` is raised. [Delegated method then tries to rescue it and show you helpful error message](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/34a1c7e284e9d307f61070dfb30f0d6ab34c74d2/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb#L197-L209).

```
exception = %(raise DelegationError, "#{self}##{method_prefix}#{method} delegated to #{to}.#{method}, but #{to} is nil: \#{self.inspect}")
```

You see, it calls `inspect` to get printable version of your object. Unfortunately, it calls `.to_s`, which is where infinite recursion begins.

Comment: Aaaah I see. I actually recently found out I could override the `inspect` and `to_s` methods of my classes to make console debugging much easier, but then I seem to fall into every trap... do you happen to have guidelines/tips when doing that ?

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris: yeah, don't do that. :) At least, don't override `inspect`.

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris: for easy debugging in console, I use `awesome_print`

Comment: I find it convenient though to call `User.where(...).first` and to have `Jonh Smith <john.smith@example.com> (Admin)` showing up in the console instead of some `User<#345629>`

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris: True. However, what if tomorrow you need more fields? Or less? Will you change `.inspect` again? Not worth it for me.

Comment: Oh actually I'm still using `awesome_print` when I need deep debugging, but often I have to do some operation on the database, and just getting the name/email is enough for me to understand which object I'm manipulating. As you said there can be a lot of fields on an object, and when I print with `ap` I often have to scroll a lot, so I'm using `inspect` as a small summary

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris: and it works well. Except when it doesn't :) (like here)